# How to set value to input type file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input type file multiple.When i add photo then photo view above as added photo.Problem is deleting photo.When i click close icon and delete photo ,photo is deleting only from as element html but not from input file.

Then i thought that i can make an array as keep current photos.I did it but o dont know how can i set value to input type file.Browser has security and doesnt allow to do it.

this is gonna my current array

```
var current_array = []; 

$(".photos").on("click", "li .fa-times", function () {
        if ($(this).next().attr("data-name") != undefined) {
            CreateSelectForDeletedPhoto($(this).next().attr("data-name"), $("select[name='DeletePhotos']"));
        }
//this delete from html
        $(this).parent().remove()
//this has to delete from input but not did it
        DeleteFileFromInput($("#Upload"), $(this).next().data("name"));
    })
```

this is DeleteFileFromInput function

```
function DeleteFileFromInput(wrapper, fileName) {
        if (current_array.length == 0) {
            var files = document.getElementById("Upload").files;
            var array = MakeAnArrayOfFiles(files);

            current_array = SpliceFileFromArray(array, fileName);
        }
        else {
            SpliceFileFromArray(current_array, fileName);
        }
    }
```

this is additional functions

I take all files from input and make array

```
function MakeAnArrayOfFiles(files) {
    var array = [];
    for (var file of files) {
        array.push(file);
    }
    return array;
}
```

then every time splice file that user want to delete

```
function SpliceFileFromArray(array, fileName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].name == fileName) {
            if (i == 0) {
                array.splice(i - 1, 1);
            } else {
                array.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

last i have an array that i want to upload files but how can i set that array to input?

Comment: Add your html. You can try to delete input node and create again with the same properties.

Comment: HTML (the server, actually) will not allow physical deletion of a file from the code directly (a security measure), javascript even so. You will need to send a request to the server and ask it (nicely) to remove the file from disk. Don't forget now...

Comment: @RenevanderLende I think the user wants to give the user to delete files before sending the remaining files to the server.

Comment: Not entirely sure, read 'photo is deleting only from as element html but not from input file'. Interpreting 'input file' as physical file.